# Data is not for 2nd time saving when first time it throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Following is the code segment I used to save two objects to same data.here Comment field is mandotary field.and the DataContext object instance is intilialized in the constructor of the class. 
When I give comment field as "NULL" for the `Obj1` saving both objects are failing but when I give `Obj1.Comment="somthing"` and `Obj2.Comment=NULL` the first one is save to the database.
I can avoid this declaring a new data context inside the `SaveObj` method.But I want to know why is this happening.does this DataContext going to an error state ? Does any one has idea the reason to happen to this

```
 public bool SaveObjectList(exemp List)
    {
        try
        {
            SaveObject(List.object1);
            SaveObject(List.object2);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false; 
        }
        return true;
    }

   public bool SaveObject(Exemp object)
   {  
          try{
                Table newObj = new Table()
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Comment = exemption.Comment
                };
                newContext.Table.InsertOnSubmit(newObj);                                                                           
                newContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
         catch{
            return false;
            }
      return true;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe if you didn't swallow the exception, but instead *at least* logged it, you'd see why it was being thrown...

Comment: hi Jon Skeet, I know reason for throwing the exception.but the matter is 1st time there's a issue.but in 2nd object there isnt.but it also throws the exception.

Comment: The same exception? And what is the exception details?

Comment: in the first object i sent comment field as null(it is a not null) field,it throws that saying "Comment is null,cannot insert"(something like this).In the second object i have set the Comment field to a value.but the same exception occurs.